# checking elements on either side of current element in list

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array:

```
array1 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]
```

I'd like to iterate through the elements and if there is a 2 that is not next to another 2, either on the left or right, I want to convert that 2 to a 1. I could create a new array, instead of modifying the old one, but I don't know how to "check" what the elements on either side of the array are first.

Comment: you can try iterating over index. then, the value on the left would be `index - 1` and the value on the right would be `index + 1`

Comment: You can just use a boolean variable, like `if_present = False`, inside a loop that iterates over the list and if you find a 2 set the boolean to `True` and on every iteration check if the current element is 2 and if `if_present` is set to `True` change the value to `1` (whichever you want, current or left) or else set `if_present` to `False` and carry on with the next iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pad your original array with -1 at the beginning and end to avoid an index error, iterate, then remove the padding as below.

```
array1 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]

array1.insert(0, -1)
array1.append(-1)
for i in range(1, len(array1) - 1):
    if array1[i] == 2 and array1[i-1] != 2 and array1[i+1] != 2:
        array1[i] = 1
array1 = array1[1:-1]
print(array1)
```

It prints [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]

Answer (score 2):

```
array1 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]
array2 = []

for i in range(len(array1)):
  if array1[i] == 2:
    if array1[i-1] != 2 and array1[i+1] != 2:
      array2.append(1)
    else:
      array2.append(2)
  else:
    array2.append(array1[i])
```

will give
`[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]`

Comment: got it yea thats what I was thinking at first, I just thought it was impossible to index like that for some reason. Thanks

Comment: This solution gives you a 'list index out of range error for a an array like array1 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2].  See my solution below.

Comment: You are right, but such an array is not stated in the question.

Comment: Yes, but good code needs to remain free of error in boundary conditions, not just work for a specific example.